# Check continuity (dates) in time series data in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, time, time-series

I want to check if there are gaps in my time-series data for more than 3 months. I have one column in my data frame with the Dates MM-DD-YY. Someone could suggest me any idea to do that? I tried with testdat package of R but it is not available for the last version (4.0.2)

Comment: Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package lubridate to work with dates format.
Then you'll juste have to create another column (let's call it B), the lag of your first column (let's call it A).
You can then create another column C, the difference between A and B.